# When I run following url on my browser it runs fine but when i use php function its getting 505 Page . Can any one help me with that

Tags: php

$output = file_get_contents("http://www.canadapost.ca/cpc2/addrm/hh/current/indexa/caONu-e.asp");
   var_dump($output);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP 505 Status means the webserver does not support the HTTP version used by the client (in this case, your PHP program).

What version of PHP are you running, and what HTTP/Web package(s) are you using in your PHP program?

[edit...]

Some servers deliberately block some browsers -- your code may "look like" a browser that the server is configured to ignore. I would particularly check the user agent string that your code is passing along to the server.

Comment: I am using PHP Version 5.1.4 and Apache 2.0 if I run http://www.google.com then it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Check in your PHP installation (php.ini file) if the [allow_url_fopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled.

If not, any calls to file_get_contents will fail.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.

That site could be blocking the server that you're using to access it.

When you run the URL from your browser, your own ISP is used to get the information and display in your browser.  But when you run from PHP, the ISP of your web host is used to get the information, then it passes it back to you.

Maybe you can do this to check and see what kind of headers its returning for you?

```
 $headers=get_headers("http://www.canadapost.ca/cpc2/addrm/hh/current/indexa/caONu-e.asp");
 print_r($headers);
```

Comment: It actually doesn't work when I use file_get_contents for me either, and it returns a 500 error. Using redbot it seems fine though http://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.canadapost.ca%2Fcpc2%2Faddrm%2Fhh%2Fcurrent%2Findexa%2FcaONu-e.asp